# Download file from data of an API response with react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to make a custom button in the AppBar of my react-admin panel to download a dump of the database.
The response of the API is a json containing information about the request plus the content of the database.

How to start a download from the client, using the json field containing the data ?
I done this for the moment:

```js
const CustomAppBar = withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...props }) => {
  const dumpDatabase = () => {
    fetch(config['api_url'] + '/dump', { method: 'GET' })
    .then(data =>  data.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json['data']);
    });
  }

  return (
    <AppBar {...props}>
      <Typography
            variant="inherit"
            color="inherit"
            className={classes.title}
            id="react-admin-title"
      />
      <span className={classes.spacer} />
      <Tooltip title="Dump Database">
        <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={dumpDatabase} >
          <SaveIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </AppBar>
  );
});
```

The `console.log(json['data']);` is the part I'm trying to replace to a download. I have very low experience with reat-admin and javascript in general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I found a working solution you can use. You have to create a blob object and asign it to a link, then you autoclick it via the script.

```js
dumpDatabase = () => {
    fetch(config['api_url'] + '/dump', { method: 'GET' })
    .then(data =>  data.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json['result'] === 'success')
      {
          // Creating the blob file and its url
          var blob = new Blob([json['data']], {type: 'application/json'}); 
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          var date = Moment(new Date()).format("YYYY_MM_DD-HH_mm_ss");

          // Creating the hyperlink and auto click it to start the download
          let link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.download = 'dump_' + date + '.json';
          link.click();
      }
    });
  }
```